# Как в Yii2 реализовать контроль доступа пользователей к своим записям (постам)

Tags: yii2, gridview, rbac

Всех приветствую!
Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией следующей конструкции:
Есть пользователи, у каждого имеются свои записи(посты), которые сохраняются в БД и выводятся в Gridview Yii2.
Как сделать так, чтобы авторизованный пользователь имел доступ только к своим записям их просмотру и редактированию?
Настроил в проекте RBAC, по данной инструкции: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXhzSN_InV0
В БД имеются 2 таблицы user и requests(посты).

Модель

```
public static function tableName(): string
{
    return 'requests';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [

        [['theme', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        ['theme', 'string', 'min' => 10],
        [['text', 'service', 'category', 'priority'], 'safe'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['filename'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['file'], 'file'],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels(): array
{
    return [
        'theme' => 'Тема обращения',
        'email' => 'Е-майл',
        'text' => 'Содержание',
        'filename' => 'Файл',
        'category' => 'Категория',
        'service' => 'Сервис',
        'priority' => 'Приоритет',
        'created_at' => 'Создано',
        'updated_at' =>'Изменено'
    ];
}


public function getAuthor (): ActiveQuery
{
  return $this->hasOne(User::class(),['id'=>'user_id']);
}




public function behaviors(): array
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::class,
            'attributes' => [
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],

            ],
            // если вместо метки времени UNIX используется datetime:
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),

        ],

    ];
}
```

}

Контроллер

```
class RequestsController extends Controller



{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::class,
            'only' => ['index'],
            'rules' => [

                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],


                ],

                [

                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,

                ],

                [
                    'actions' => ['loqout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],

                ],


            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::class,
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, почему это должно быть связанно с RBAC, который отвечает за доступ к просмотру и редактированию определенных ролей, а чтобы показывать посты пользователей, так выводите только те посты, у которых user_id = текущему пользователю, вот и всё)
ID текущего можно так взять - Yii::$app->user->getId()